# Mac Numbers Shortcut Help

Tags: shortcut, numbers, formatting

In [Numbers](https://www.apple.com/numbers/) (I'm currently running v3.6.2) after I have selected a cell/row/whatever, I want, without irritating my carpal tunnels, to format that text strikethrough.

In [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel), I just had to add the little strikethrough button to the top bar and *whoosh* it's that much easier to strike items from my ToDo lists.

In Numbers at the moment the only way I know to strike text is expand the right side format pane, click Text, find and click the advanced gear dropdown thing, and click the little radio button next to *Strikethrough*.

It's too much to bear! Just get me a single-click or two-key-combo solution!

Comment: You can also go to **Format** > **Font** > **Strikethrough**

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no shortcut for strikethrough as far as I know. But you can try setting up a shortcut for "Strikethrough" in **System Preferences**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X you can assign your own keyboard shortcuts very easily.

Just go to **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**

Here you can add new shortcut for any application like this:

[image: Keyboard preferences with custom shortcuts]